# Reducing a 100Km OS Map to usable size

Tags: qgis

I have downloaded a 100Km map from OS, but the problem is that it is far larger than I need and hence takes a long time to load every refresh in QGIS. Is there a way to cut down the size of the accompanying shape files to a more manageable size of, say, 10Km square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is VectorMap District vectors I guess? If you are happy about working from a command line or in a terminal you can clip a shapefile to a precise 10 km square using a command like this:

```
ogr2ogr -spat 460000 190000 470000 200000 -f "ESRI Shapefile" SU_Road_clipped.shp SU_Road.shp
```

where "460000 190000" forms the coordinate of the bottom left-hand corner of a rectangle and "470000 200000" forms the coordinate of the top right-hand corner of the same rectangle. The original shapefile will be clipped to a subset having the extents specified by the rectangle (the output will be a new shapefile, the original will not be harmed in any way).

Nick.

Comment: I've downloaded ogr2ogr from FWTools (Is that the best place as it's given me 100s of new files!!!), tired it and it works, brilliant thanks. Better than the Sextante option

Comment: FWTools is great, but in fact if you have QGIS you already have GDAL/OGR installed :) N.

Comment: I thought I had but could not work out how to use it!!!

Comment: I should have mentioned that I could not find an ogr2ogr executable on my PC which was why I installed FWTools

Comment: It should be in C:\Programs (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin if you installed by standalone installer, else C:\Osgeo4w\bin.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GRASS v.generalize tool, you can use it with the qgis/grass plugin or now also with the sextante plugin (the last option is easier as you don't need to get deep into the grass data model).

Comment: most probably the op wants to clip/extract the 100 km² data to parts of 10Km² each..

Comment: That's right. I have not used Sextante or Grass as it was not needed for my purposes. Grass does not seem to fit the bill, but would Sextante?

Comment: OK, I have just installed Sextante and I think it will do the trick, so thanks Giovanni